# Cannon MP140 set up

Tags: printing, canon, scanner

Anyone help me please. I want to install my Canon printer-scanner MP140 with Ubuntu with results so far. I can't print excel, words, pdf documents.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "system -▸ administration -▸ printers", configure it as MP150 and it will work. ;)

Comment: This answer (8 years old though it might be) did not work for me.